# hibernate - how to correctly define relations between entities?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying do maintain a code that was developed when I was busy doing other parts of the system and am taking a beat from some entities related to each other.

The scenario is this:

```
EntityX has one or more EntityA;
EntityA has one or more EntityB;
EntityB has one or more EntityC;
EntityC has one or more EntityD;
```

My Entities classes, are:

```
public class EntityX {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, insertable = true)
    private String id;

    @OneToMay(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "joinTableX_A",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idX", referencedColumn= "id" ) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idA", referencedColumn = "id") })
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<A> aList;

    // getters and setters

public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, insertable = true)
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColun(name = "idX")
    private X x;

    @OneToMay(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "joinTableA_B",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idA", referencedColumn= "id" ) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idB", referencedColumn = "id") })
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> bList;

    // getters and setters


public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, insertable = true)
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColun(name = "idA")
    private A a;

    @OneToMay(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "joinTableB_C",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idB", referencedColumn= "id" ) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idC", referencedColumn = "id") })
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<C> cList;

    // getters and setters


public class EntityC {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, insertable = true)
    private String id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColun(name = "idB")
    private B b;

    @OneToMay(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "joinTableC_D",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idC", referencedColumn= "id" ) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idD", referencedColumn = "id") })
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<D> dList;

    // getters and setters
```

What I am trying to do is:

1. When x is deleted, all children a, b, c and d are deleted;
2. When a is deleted, all children b, c and d are deleted but x is not;
3. When b is deleted, all children c and d are delete, but x and a are not;
4. When c is deleted, all children d are deleted, but x, a and b are not.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I get this scenario working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining your relationships like this, using JPA annotations, you'll even make your code simpler by using the following method:

```
public class EntityX {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, insertable = true)
    private String id;

    @OneToMay(mappedBy = "x", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<A> aList;

    // getters and setters

}
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, insertable = true)
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idX")
    private X x;

    //and so on

    // getters and setters

}
```

I think its a better Idea to let JPA handle your join column names, unless you have a restriction